# Dimensional matrix

Tags: tables, math-mode, matrices

I'm pretty new to Latex. I'm using a template from my institution so I don't have to be an expert... I want to implement this dimensional matrix:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c||c|c|c|c|c|}
          & W & $U_\infty$ & $\eta$ & $\rho$ & d \\
        \midrule
        \midrule
        M & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        L & 1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
        T & -2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\label{...}
\end{table}
```

I want it to be displayed as a formula (\begin{equation} ...) in order to be able to reference it as an equation. It should have the same look though. I can't just use a normal matrix as I don't know how to put the variables and the dimensions in if I want the separating lines. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you ask a question it is better to give a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that, in particular, compiles because this makes it much clearer what you want (for example, your question does not say that you are using [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)) and also much easier for people to help you.

To answer your question, just put your table inside an equation using the `array` environment:

[image]

For the reasons explained in the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual I would drop the vertical bars and typeset this as:

[image]

Of course, you should do whatever suits you best!

Here is the full MWE for producing these tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{c||c|c|c|c|c|}
          & W & U_\infty & \eta & \rho & d \\
        \midrule
        \midrule
        M & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        L & 1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
        T & -2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{array}
    \label{E:mymatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{cccccc}\toprule
          & W & U_\infty & \eta & \rho & d \\
        \midrule
        M & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        L & 1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
        T & -2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{array}
    \label{E:mymatrix2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `array` environment which is the math mode version of tabular that assumes its entries in math mode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{c||c|c|c|c|c|}
          & W & U_\infty & \eta & \rho & d \\
        \midrule
        \midrule
        M & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        L & 1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
        T & -2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{array}
\label{eq:lala}
\end{equation}
As can be seen from \eqref{eq:lala}, our eyes are working.
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't use the vertical lines though (actually no lines would be better)

Answer (score 4):

An example with another alignment of the columns, and a different layout, which shows tables *may* have vertical and horizontal rules, and still look ‘professional’:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names,  table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sisetup{table-format=-1,table-number-alignment=center}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{array}{c!{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\vrule width2pt}*{5}{S}}
          & {W} & {U_\infty} & {\eta} & {\rho} & {d} \\
        \arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}\midrule[1pt]
        M & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        L & 1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
        T & -2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}
\label{eq:lala}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]